# Pandas: Drop quasi-duplicates by column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that, let's say, looks like this (which I'm putting into a DF):

```
[
['john', '1', '1', '2016'],
['john', '1', '10', '2016'],
['sally', '3', '5', '2016'],
['sally', '4', '1', '2016']
]
```

`columns` are `['name', 'month', 'day', 'year']`

I basically want to output a new DF with only the oldest row for each person. So it should contain two rows, one for john on 1/1/16 and one for sally on 3/5/16.

I have always had a tough time with this sort of selection inside DF's and was hoping someone could offer some advice on how to accomplish the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort the data frame by `year, month, day` and then take the first row from each `name`:

```
df.sort_values(by = ['year', 'month', 'day']).groupby('name').first()

#   month   day year
# name          
# john  1   1   2016
#sally  3   5   2016
```

*Data*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['john', '1', '1', '2016'],
                   ['john', '1', '10', '2016'],
                   ['sally', '3', '5', '2016'],
                   ['sally', '4', '1', '2016']], 
                   columns = ['name', 'month', 'day', 'year'])
```

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1***
use `pd.to_datetime` to parse ['year', 'month', 'day'] columns.
`groupby('name')` then take `first`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
df.sort_values(['name', 'date']).groupby('name').first()
```

[image]

***Option 2***
Same `pd.to_datetime` usage.
`groupby('name')` take `idxmin` to locate smallest date.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
df.ix[df.groupby('name').date.idxmin()]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorting by `name` is not necessary, is it?

Comment: No, but I wanted to to keep names together if I were to look at an intermdeiate result.  Not necessary though.