# Pandas drop only certain column values when trying to remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582860/pandas-drop-quasi-duplicates-by-column-values), but not quite. I have a CSV with the following kind of structure

```
| id | entrydate  | sales | purchases |
| -- | -----------| ----- | --------- |
| 1  | 05/03/2017 | 10    | 1         |
| 2  | 05/03/2017 | 20    | 2         |
| 3  | 05/03/2017 | 30    | 3         |
| 1  | 05/03/2017 | 40    | 1         |
```

I'm reading this into a dataframe, and I want to get daily aggregates of sales and purchases (individual id doesn't matter, just daily aggregates).

First, however, I need to remove duplicates. This is tripping me up, because if you take the example above, for **id 1**, there are two entries on the same day, but multiple entries in the `purchases` column are to be considered duplicates, whereas multiple entries in the `sales` column are valid, so the correct grouping would result in

```
| id | entrydate  | sales | purchases |
| -- | -----------| ----- | --------- |
| 1  | 05/03/2017 | 50    | 1         |
| 2  | 05/03/2017 | 20    | 2         |
| 3  | 05/03/2017 | 30    | 3         |
```

and then getting the daily aggregate would give me

```
|entrydate   | sales | purchases |
| -----------| ----- | --------- |
| 05/03/2017 | 100   | 6         |
```

I was trying to remove the `purchases` duplicates using

```
df = pandas.read_csv('../my-csv.csv', parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, usecols=my_columns, dtype=my_dtypes).rename(columns=str.lower).assign(date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['entrydate'], format="%d/%m/%Y")).set_index('date')
```

[image]

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['id', 'entrydate', 'purchases'])
df.drop(['id'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')).sum()
```

but while this will remove the duplicate `purchases` it also removes valid `sales`

[image]

---

Image for the solution by A-Za-z

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby twice, first to aggregate sales

```
df.sales = df.groupby('id').sales.transform('sum')
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.groupby(df.entrydate).sum().reset_index()


    entrydate   sales   purchases
0   2017-05-03  100     6
```

EDIT: To account for sum over different dates

```
df.sales = df.groupby(['id', 'date']).sales.transform('sum')
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.groupby('date')['sales', 'purchases'].sum().reset_index()
```

You get

```
    date        sales   purchases
0   2017-03-05  100     6
1   2017-03-06  40      1
```

Comment: This almost works for me, except when another date is present in the csv, so say I have a row in the csv like `1,06/03/2017,40,1`, it seems to sum the sales across all days for that id, and use that value for all dates. See the update screenshot in the question

Answer (score 1):

If you groupby entrydate you can aggregate both sales and purchases:

```
In [11]: df.groupby("entrydate").agg({"sales": "sum", "purchases": "sum"})
Out[11]:
            sales  purchases
entrydate
05/03/2017    100          7
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I need to tidy up my question. I want to sum sales, but for purchases, I first want to remove the duplicate entry per id, and then sum. So sales would indeed be aggregated overall to 100, but purchases would be 6 (as only one entry per date per id counts)

Comment: @PhilipO'Brien Why should it pick 40 over 30? or should it take both?

Comment: It should take (sum) both from the sales column but only take one from the purchases column (the daily entry in purchases will always be the same, so it doesn't matter which one is taken)

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'entrydate': {0: '05/03/2017',
  1: '05/03/2017',
  2: '05/03/2017',
  3: '05/03/2017',
  4: '06/03/2017',
  5: '06/03/2017',
  6: '06/03/2017',
  7: '06/03/2017'},
 'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 1},
 'purchases': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 1},
 'sales': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 10, 5: 20, 6: 30, 7: 40}})
```

**Solution**

```
#First group by entrydate and id, summing sales and take the max from purchases(removing duplicates). Then another group by to sum sales and purchases.
df.groupby(['entrydate','id']).agg({'sales':sum, 'purchases':max}).groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()
Out[431]: 
    entrydate  purchases  sales
0  05/03/2017          6    100
1  06/03/2017          6    100
```